# Python: Json dumps escape quote

Tags: python, json

There is a POST request which works perfectly when I pass the data as below:

```
url = 'https://www.nnnow.com/api/product/details'

requests.post(url, data="{\"styleId\":\"BMHSUR2HTS\"}", headers=headers)
```

But when I use `json.dumps()` on a dictionary and send the response, I do not get the response (response code 504), using `headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` . Have also tried json parameter of Post requests.

```
requests.post(url, data=json.dumps({"styleId":"BMHSUR2HTS"}), headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
```

Now, the data returned by `json.dumps({"styleId":"BMHSUR2HTS"})` and 
`"{\"styleId\":\"BMHSUR2HTS\"}"` is not the same.

`json.dumps({"styleId":"BMHSUR2HTS"}) == "{\"styleId\":\"BMHSUR2HTS\"}"` gives `False` even though a print on both shows a similar string.

How can I get the same format as `"{\"styleId\":\"BMHSUR2HTS\"}"` from a dictionary `{"styleId":"BMHSUR2HTS"}` ?

Comment: The only difference between your string and the result of `json.dumps` is that the latter will put a space after the colon; that is not significant in JSON and is not the cause of your problem.

Comment: What happens when you just pass the actual `dict`? Eg, `requests.post(url, data={"styleId":"BMHSUR2HTS"}, headers=headers)`. That's the form use in the [requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart) example.

Comment: You can get the same result using `json.dumps({"styleId":"BMHSUR2HTS"}, separators=(',',':'))` but I can't see why it could not work because of that

Comment: @DanielRoseman : I have added the url so you could also see that it doesn't work with `json.dumps`

Comment: @PM2Ring: I get a 400 response, Bad request

Comment: Can you try with simple quote wrapping? Wont solve it but will make it clearer.

Comment: it works when you use `separators=(',', ':')`, they are probably using a weird parser...

Comment: I tried another alternate that did work: 
`data="{\"styleId\":\"" + "BMHSUR2HTS" + "\"}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print the `json.dumps({"styleId":"BMHSUR2HTS"})`, you will notice two things:

1. your output is a string (just try `type(json.dumps({"styleId":"BMHSUR2HTS"}))`);
2. if you pay attention the output will add a space between the json name and value: `{"styleId": "BMHSURT2HTS"}`.

Not sure how do you want to handle this, and in your entry code, but there are 2 main options to workaround this issue:

1. Replace the space on json.dumps output: `json.dumps({"styleId":"BMHSUR2HTS"}).replace(': ', ':')`
2. Convert all to json by using eval(): `eval(json.dumps({"styleId":"BMHSUR2HTS"}))` and `eval(YOUR_JSON_STRING)`

I hope this helps you.